# How to use currying function to work if one of the argument contains multiple value?

Tags: javascript

I have a higher order function , though the first case `multiply(4,5)` works as expected but is it possible to pass multiple argument like `multiply(2)(4, 5)`. In this case the answer is 8, but can a curried function be created in such a way so that it gives 40 as result

```js
function multiply(s) {
  return function(b) {
    return s * b;
  }

}

console.log(multiply(4)(5))
console.log(multiply(2)(4, 5))
```

Comment: You can either use two nested `multiply` calls or rewrite the function. Also, your first case is `multiply(4)(5)`, not `multiply(4, 5)`

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6t5qd1g3/1//) ?

Comment: @NickParsons great

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks

Comment: @brk no worries, check Nina's answer for the option to pass arguments in both the first and second functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and collect all arguments on both functions and return the reduced result.

```js
function multiply(...a) {
    return function(...b) {
        return [...a, ...b].reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    };
}

console.log(multiply(4)(5));       //  20
console.log(multiply(2)(4, 5));    //  40
console.log(multiply(3, 2)(4, 5)); // 120
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function multiply(s) {
  return function(b) {
    for(key in arguments)s*=arguments[key];
    return s;
  }

}

console.log(multiply(4)(5))
console.log(multiply(2)(4, 5))
```

I think its best to use arguments property in your case.

Comment: Why is it best? Also could you add some explanation to your code please?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using `arguments`:

```
function multiply(s) {
  return function () {
    return Array.from(arguments).reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator * currentValue;
    }, s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way if you have one or more `b` arguments :

```js
function multiply(s) {
  // Will contain the multiplication of all b arguments
  var result = 1;

  // ...b will return an the array arguments passed
  return function(...b) {

    // Loop through each of this array and update result
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      result *= b[i];
    }

    // return the final result
    return s * result;
  }

}

console.log(multiply(4)(5))
console.log(multiply(2)(4, 5))
```